# Cannot validate signature using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt library on AAD/Microsoft-Identity id_token

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-identity-platform

I am using a WebApp in Azure with Azure Active Directory authentication turned on and and am pulling the **id_token** from the **/.auth/me** page here:

[image]

From my understanding when I paste this into JWT.io it validates the signature by looking up the OpenId Configuration at **[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)**

and then uses the **jwks_uri** (**[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/discovery/v2.0/keys](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/discovery/v2.0/keys)**) to find the public signing key (x5c Array) based on the kid from the JWT header here:

[image]

However when I try to replicate this scenario in C# I am unable to validate the signature using the **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** library.

Here are a few of my attempts and results:

**ATTEMPT**

```
        var idToken = "{id_token}";
        var signingKey = "{x5c[0]}";


        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + signingKey + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"));

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };

        try
        {
            claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(idToken, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
            Console.WriteLine($"{claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

**RESULT**

> IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:  kid:
> 'System.String'. Exceptions caught:  'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
> token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.

**ATTEMPT**

```
        var kid = "l3sQ-50cCH4xBVZLHTGwnSR7680";
        var idToken = "{id_token}";
        var signingKey = "{x5c[0]}";


        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + signingKey + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----")) { KeyId = kid, };

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };

        try
        {
            claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(idToken, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
            Console.WriteLine($"{claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

**RESULT**

> IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
> 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.  kid: 'System.String'.  Exceptions
> caught:  'System.Text.StringBuilder'. token:
> 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.

I also tried both attempts without the **"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"** and **"\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"** additions to the signing key and had the same results as well as trying with **ASCII** encoding instead of **UTF8**.

**==== UPDATE ====**

I was able to use the  **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols** and **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect** libraries to validate the token using the following code to create the signing keys:

```
var issuer = jwtToken.Issuer;
var audiences = jwtToken.Audiences;
var issuerOpenIdUri = $"{issuer}/.well-known/openid-configuration";

string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = issuerOpenIdUri;
var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever()); 
OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
```

...and then use the **OpenIdConnectConfiguration** to assign the keys to the **TokenValidatetionParameters**:

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
   ValidAudiences = audiences,
   ValidIssuer = issuer,

   IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

   ValidateLifetime = true,
   ValidateAudience = true,
   ValidateIssuer = true
};
```

However I am still curious why my original attempts would not work. I would like to understand a little better what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey uses the certificate thumbprint in base 16 in its KeyId. Azure Active Directory KeyId uses the certificate thumbprint in base 64.
To use same key ID format as that used by Azure Active directory ,It will be possible  (Just the way you did)  with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever  and by using signing keys this way

```
myTokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys = myOpenIdConnectionConfiguration.SigningKeys;
```

The error may also occur when “aud” claim doesn’t match the audience which is nothing but the  client Id and  can be mitigated by giving proper scopes in AAD and in code with proper audience and scope and by granting consent.